# How can I find out what ham radio events or contest are going on?

Tags: contest

Looking for a good place to find out what contest or events are going at the present.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent resource:

http://www.hornucopia.com/contestcal/

Comment: Could you add a bit of info about what makes it excellent?

Comment: All you need to know about a contest (start and stop dates and times, exchange, modes, reporting site, rules, and so on) are included on the above quoted site.  I have used this site for a number of years.  I am not a "contester" in the sense of striving to gain points and win, but I enjoy the contest as a means of getting desired QTH or DX or just high speed CW exercises.  I am close to 100 percent CW contester only.  Maybe one SSB contest a year, last week's ARRL Sweepstakes SSB contest is it.